# How do I get list of sharepoint items in a folder using Microsoft Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I'm able to make graph calls to get all items in a list but how can we get/filter items inside a list folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems not a direct way to achieve it. If I filter using below, I get the error "**Field 'FileDirRef' cannot be referenced in filter or orderby as it is not indexed.**".

```
&filter=fields/FileDirRef eq '/sites/lz/Lists/cl/folder'
```

As a workaround, we can get the list items and then filter the items base on the **FileDirRef** field in code.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/lz.sharepoint.com,{Site GUID},{Web GUID}/lists/{List GUID}/items?expand=fields(select=id,Title,FileDirRef)
```

Comment: Thanks for your enlightening suggestion. The error would go away by adding header key value `Prefer: HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly`. but even after this there's no results for the given filtering criteria.

Answer (score 1):

You could utilize the following query to retrieve items under a sub folder:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/drive/root:/{folder-url}:/children
```

Here is an example using [Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet):

```
var folderUrl = "/Archive/2018"; //relative path
var site = graphClient.Sites[siteId];
var list = site.Lists[listId]; 
var items = await list.Drive.Root.ItemWithPath(folderUrl).Children.Request().Expand("ListItem").GetAsync();
//print list item details  
foreach (var item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.ListItem.WebUrl);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vadim but the above approach only works when you are dealing with Sharepoint Library lists not plain lists.